# Composer post-update list of updated packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I need a list of the updated composer packages.

I tried to get the list of the updated packages via composer command events `post-update-cmd` and `post-package-update` like described in the [composer docs section about scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events).

My class function receives the $event object but there is no function `$event->getOperation()->getPackage();` like described in the docs.

I also searched in the values for some information about the updated packages but had no luck.

Just a list of the updated packages would be great.

Comment: Make sure you're using the `PackageEvent` class and not the `Event` one.

Comment: I already use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent like the docs describe, may i have to find an updater package event, thx for the hint

Comment: I also can read the packages from the composer.json. The same result. An easy way to just get the updated packages would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin already that prints the changelog of `composer update` operations:

https://packagist.org/packages/pyrech/composer-changelogs

At least this may act as a template for you to learn from.